# Drush 8 database connection issue

Tags: database, drush

I'm having trouble connecting to my databases. It worked a few days ago but can't seem to figure why it doesn't work now. It's a D8-site. Drush version is 8.1.12.

I've double-checked both the alias-file and settings.php-files (both on server & local) and database settings all appear correct. My local site runs on Mamp 4.1.1. and network access is allowed.

Here's the error I get when running sql-sync `drush sql-sync @local @dev`. Rsync works fine.

```
Unable to load class Drush\Sql\Sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [error]
exception 'Drush\Sql\SqlException' with message 'Unable to find a matching SQL Class. Drush cannot find your database connection details.' in /vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc:541                [error]
Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc(252): drush_sql_get_class()
#1 [internal function]: drush_sql_dump()
#2 /vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(422): call_user_func_array('drush_sql_dump', Array)
#3 /vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#4 [internal function]: drush_command()
#5 /vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(199): call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#6 /vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#7 /vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#8 /vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()
#9 {main}
sql-dump failed.
```

And here's the aliases.drushrc.php (my local copy of course includes credentials:))

```
<?php

/* Tambourhinoceros Site */

$aliases["local"] = array (
 'root' => '', // local path
 'uri' => 'local.tambourhinoceros.net',  // local uri
 'path-aliases' =>
 array (
   '%dump-dir' => '/tmp',
   '%drush' => '/usr/local/bin',
   '%site' => 'sites/default',
 ),
 'remote-user' => 'tamb_dev', 
 'ssh-options' => '-T',
 'databases' =>
 array (
   'default' =>
   array (
     'default' =>
     array (
        'database' => '', // local database 
        'username' => '', // local database user
        'password' => '', // local database pw
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '8889',
        'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'prefix' => '',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

$aliases["dev"] = array (
  'root' => '', // remote path
  'uri' => 'drupal-85630-297475.cloudwaysapps.com', // remote uri
  'path-aliases' =>
  array (
  ),
  'remote-host' => '', remote IP
  'remote-user' => '', remote User
  'command-specific' =>
 array (
   'rsync' =>
   array (
     'mode' => 'rlptzO',
     'verbose' => true,
     'no-perms' => true,
   ),
 ),
 'databases' =>
 array (
   'default' =>
   array (
     'default' =>
     array (
        'database' => '', remote database
        'username' => '', remote  user
        'password' => '', remote pw
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '',
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'prefix' => '',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
?>
```

Comment: Is it this? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186446/unable-to-to-find-sql-class-drush-cannot-find-your-database-connection-details

Comment: How do I check if it is? I'm not sure what the commands used in that post does... Sorry for being a noob:)

Comment: Please post the command you typed.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in @cilefen. Original question is updated to include the command.

Comment: What are the relevant drush site alias configurations?

Comment: @cilefen added to original question

Comment: did you try to set `127.0.0.1` instead `localhost` for host, or to set drush path in `path-aliases` array for remote like `'%drush-script' => '/home/user/.config/composer/vendor/bin/drush'` for example?

Comment: @mixerowsky I've tried now. Nothing changed when I set host to 127.0.0.1. When added the location for my drush installing I get a permissions-error:  env: /Users/kristofferrom/Sites/dev.tambourhinoceros.net/vendor/drush: Permission denied
The command could not be executed successfully (returned: env: /Users/kristofferrom/Sites/dev.tambourhinoceros.net/vendor/drush: Permission denied

Comment: @KristofferRom I thought to add this on remote, your dev...

Comment: @mixerowsky OK, tried that adding both my local and remote paths to the dev. Same error no matter the combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. And as usual the issue turned out to be much smaller and simple than I thought...

My local path was missing the "/web" segment in the end. After adding it both rsync and sql-sync works!

Thanks for all the input people.

Comment: Where did you find the "/web" segment? In settings.php?

Answer (score 1):

It will be Solved by adding

```
--root=/full/path/to/your/webroot
```

to the drush command.

Comment: Nope, any way to debug why it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

On your local connection, try adding "unix_socket" option and point to your local mysql socket.

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => '',
  'username' => '',
  'password' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'unix_socket' => '/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
);
```

More complete steps to debugging: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/174128/25221

Comment: Sorry, didn't fix it either (using /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock)

Comment: Ah well, maybe some of the additional steps for determining the socket in this answer will help. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/174128/25221

Comment: Thanks @daggerhart. Everything except #5 works. But when running  
"mysql --socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock" I get "ysql --socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'kristofferrom'@'localhost' (using password: NO)". The user kristofferrom is my user on my local OS X and the user that MAMP defaults to. Any ideas?

Comment: That means you're reaching mysql, but not authenticating with it.  You need to pass in info for your mysql user.  For example:   `mysql -u root -p --socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock` then provide your root password when prompted.